# How to get a callback to the server when adding a post / comment to a post / repost in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Where is the callback facebook description for events in the facebook community?  In Graph, I found only functions for inst and my personal facebook page.

Comment: what events exactly? please add what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far in detail.

Comment: Do you mean webhooks? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/

Comment: For example there is a post in the facebook group.  The user has left a comment to the post and now I want to get a notification about this with the user id and comment content.
 Now I have read 10,000,000 articles about it but have not found information on how to do what I want.  I also registered a developer account, confirmed the webhooks link to my server and I think what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you can currently subscribe for updates from, is listed under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference

Only Groups for Workplace are available here, not normal groups.

What you want is currently not possible using Webhooks.